# Flash Builder generated apk file not working in my Android Mobile

Tags: air

I am using Flash Builder 4.5 Trail version With Flex SDK 4.5.
I just want to Run a simple hello world Mobile Application in my Device(Motorola Z 71).
I have followed Adobe Document for Mobile Application.
While I am installing the apk file on my Motorola z 71 device, it is giving **INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK** error.
Can anyone help me on this ..?
Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

I don't think AIR is supported on that device. The [AIR system requirements](http://www.adobe.com/products/air/systemreqs/) list ARMv7 CPU for Android devices, but the first [spec sheet](http://pdadb.net/index.php?m=specs&id=2605&c=motorola_quench_xt3_commtiva_z71) I googled suggested that the Z71 uses a Qualcomm MSM7227, which is ARMv6 architecture. So my guess is that the app will work if you try it on an ARMv7 device.